# Image dimensions in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, band, dimensions

How can one get image (band) width and height on the server side?

On the user side you do it with `image.getInfo().bands[0].dimensions`, following [Extracting information from Google Earth Engine image by row and column position?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/277514/169344)

However, it is not possible to map such a function, since `getInfo()` is a user-side function.

The task sounds extremely simple, since you always see band dimensions whenever you print an image, but how to get them as a list or a numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ee.Algorithms.Describe() (bit hidden in the documentation)

this should work :

```
var numberOfPixels = function(img){
  
  var imgDescription = ee.Algorithms.Describe( img );
  var height = ee.List( ee.Dictionary( ee.List(  ee.Dictionary( imgDescription ).get("bands") ).get(0) ).get("dimensions") ).get(0);
  var width = ee.List( ee.Dictionary( ee.List(  ee.Dictionary( imgDescription ).get("bands") ).get(0) ).get("dimensions") ).get(1);
  
  //print("width", width )
  //print("height", height )
  
  return  ee.Number( width ).multiply( ee.Number( height ) );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

```
function getDims(i) {
    return ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(i.projection()) // x and y
          .reduceRegion({
              reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
              geometry: i.geometry(),
              maxPixels: 1e9  // adjust this to suppress warnings
          });
}
```